# Chat server client error

Tags: java, kryo

I have developed an applet which has a jar chat client(used kryonet jar file) in on of its panel. In other project i am calling this applet (by converting applet project as jar file and    placed it in root path of 2nd project and supplied all jar files) it is applet is opening fine but when my chat client uses to register an error is occurred in server side(chat server which is running in different system). It is saying fallowing exception.

```
Exception in thread "Server" com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Buffer underflow.
Serialization trace:
is_server (com.garnet.panel.Network$RegisterName)
at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Input.require(Input.java:153)
at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Input.readBoolean(Input.java:554)
at      
 com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.DefaultSerializers$BooleanSerializer
.create(DefaultSerializers.java:37)
at   com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.DefaultSerializers$BooleanSerializer
.create (DefaultSerializers.java:27)
at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:626)
at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read
    (FieldSerializer.java:231)
at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:714)
at com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.KryoSerialization.read(KryoSerialization.java:57)
at com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.TcpConnection.readObject(TcpConnection.java:138)
at com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.Server.update(Server.java:190)
at com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.Server.run(Server.java:342)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

I used fallowing examples given by kryonet  [example of chat client and server](http://code.google.com/p/kryonet/source/browse/#svn/trunk/kryonet/examples/com/esotericsoftware/kryonet/examples/chat)

1) I have placed the Network class in same packages in both applications.
   2) This example works fine when i download it and run it without applying to applet.